# How to make C/C++ compiler to look for headers in a user specified path

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include-path

I'm using a library written by others which is kinda based on C for C++ usage -I think-. All inclusions used inside the headers or source files are in the form <> instead of "" even though they are not standard library files. My compiler doesn't recognize them and returns error "file not found"

An example of the problem is inside the following header:

```
#ifndef _ga_ga_h_
#define _ga_ga_h_

// Make sure that we get the configuration into each of the galib components
// that will be used.
#include <ga/gaconfig.h>

// These are the headers for all of the genetic algorithm classes.
#include <ga/GASimpleGA.h>
#include <ga/GASStateGA.h>
#include <ga/GAIncGA.h>
#include <ga/GADemeGA.h>
#include <ga/GADCrowdingGA.h>

// Here we include the headers for all of the various genome types.
#include <ga/GA1DBinStrGenome.h>
#include <ga/GA2DBinStrGenome.h>
#include <ga/GA3DBinStrGenome.h>
#include <ga/GABin2DecGenome.h>
```

I include that header inside my program using #include "ga.h" but it is very hard to change inside every header/source file in the library.

Is there a way to make the compiler use <> as if they were ""?
I tried adding the paths to "Addition include directories"from Project properties (I'm using Visual Studio), Many inclusions' errors disappeared but around 30 persisted. The strange thing is that they are in a file called "c1xx" but i don't have that file!!

thanks,

Comment: You can try adding the path to those headers in your compiler's header search path. If it'll work or not is implementation defined.

Comment: How to set or add to the default search path for include files depends on the compiler and the environment. With GCC and Clang from the command line you use the `-I` (upper case i) option.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Using <> for inclusion, the compiler will search in system include paths AND the paths that you manually set for compiler to search for include files. So your solution is to configure your compiler the path of those include files.
for example for gcc : using -I/path/to/include/directories

Comment: you can use `""` instead of `<>` if you copy headers to the include folder

Answer (score 7):

The definition is somewhat that <> is used for "system" header files, usually found in locations like /usr/include (on Unix-like systems) and "" is used for local header files.  When you compile your code, you can indicate the location of additional directories containing header files e.g. using the -I option when using GCC.  Check your compiler's documentation for the setting needed

So, e.g. on Linux and GCC, if your "ga" directory is in /usr/local/include/ga, you would use cc -I /usr/local/include.

Comment: and it has nothing to do with c or c++ code. Though name mangling can be an issue while linking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, I'm a noob, could you please clarify a bit more? so in my source, I include the file as follows:

Comment: #include "ga\ga.h" and inside that file, there are all these inclusions with <>... so I should include it like this: #include "-l\ga\ga.h"?

Comment: You can use #include <ga/whatever.h> and tell the compiler (or, rather, the C preprocessor) where the "ga" directory is: cc -I <place where ga is> myfile.c

Comment: your answer is completely wrong. <> is for `-I<path>` include **and** `-system` includes. "" is for headers besides the source .c/.cpp file.

Comment: @Peet check my comment ^

Comment: Not -I in the #include line, but on the  command line when you invoke the compiler.

Comment: @MarcBalmer you should rephrase it then, because it doesn't sound like so.

Comment: @MarcBalmer Sorry, I guess what made your answer really confuse to me was the fact that you mention system locations and give `/usr/local/include` as example for <>, sounding like it should be used for "system" locations. And the fact that you use quotes for "ga"... which gets confused with "ga" of `#include "ga"`.

Comment: The user specifically mentions the Visual Studio environment. `cc` flags and examples are not only irrelevant but also misleading.

Comment: He added the mention of Visual Studio only later, the original post had no mention of it.

Comment: Great, so now your answer should refer to it as well to continue being correct. Or at least the references to cc should be removed

Answer (score 4):

This indeed looks like a problem of telling the compiler where to look for the included header files. As mentioned in the other answers, when you do a `#include <header.h>`, header.h must be in one of the include search paths - either the system includes, or the additional paths that you are telling the compiler to look for headers. In Linux/g++ (as mentioned in the other answers here), you do that by passing in the the additional search paths in the `-I` flag. The compilation command would look something like:

`g++ -I/additional/header/search/path -o a.out your_file.cpp`

Since you are using visual studio and the MSVC compiler, the equivalent would be the `/I` flag, and the compilation command would look something like:

`CL /I\additional\header\path your_file.cpp`

I am assuming you are using Visual Studio - you can also configure that from the project properties. Go to `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General` and modify `Additional Include Directories`. Refer these for more info:

[Setting C++ compiler and build properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-160)

[Additional include directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 1):

First about the difference between `<header>` and `<file>`. The standards (both C and C++) only specifies that

```
#include <header>
```

includes an *header* named *header* and that

```
#include "file"
```

includes a *source file* named *file*, if none is found an header named *file* is included instead.

What are *headers* and how they differ from *source files* is left to the implementation. In practice they are files as well. So `#include <header>` is looking for a file in some places, `#include "file"` is looking for a file in some other places and if not found at the same places as for `#include <file>`.

AFAIK all compilers

- are able to search for *source files* in the directory of the file containing the include directive
- are able to be given a list of directories to search for *headers* before their default search path.

ISTR that Visual C++ is also searching for a *source file* in the directories of files indirectly including it. (I can't confirm currently if my memory is good; that behavior is AFAIK unachievable with other compilers so I never relied on it and -- by luck? -- it never resulted in a different behavior for my programs).

Obviously that behavior is more or less customizable. For instance with g++ is possible to:

- disable the search of a *source file* in the directory of the file containing the include directive (with `-I-`, note that `-I-` is deprecated since gcc 4.0 -- 2005 -- when `-iquote` has been introduced and there is no non-deprecated way to achieve this)
- to add a list of directories to search for *source files* and not for *headers* (with `-iquote` and it's an effect of `-I-` as well)
- to give a list of directories to search for *headers* after the default list of directories (with `-idirafter`)
- to give a list of directories to search for *headers* which are processed specially (with `-isystem`; less warnings are given for constructs in those files which help when using the "treat warnings as errors" flags, they aren't considered as dependencies with `-MM` and `-MMD` which usually is a nuisance)

---

Now for your problem. The library has been visibly designed to be used by adding the directory containing the directory `ga` to the include path. That should be enough as I'm unaware of any compiler modifying its search path for *headers* depending on how the file including the *header* has been included.

Note that `c1xx` is probably the name of the compiler executable, not the name of a file trying to include another (again, I'm not in position to ensure that's the case now, but compare with `cc1plus` which is the name of the compiler for GCC -- `g++` is a driver handling several things and executing `cc1plus` to handle the compilation of C++ code)

Answer (score -2):

If you do on the command line:

```
echo | gcc -v -E -x c++ -
```

You will get an output with the default include directories for C++. Those are the built in system's include search paths.

If you compile with `g++ -I/some/dir -o foo foo.cpp`, you are adding an additional include search path (`/some/dir`) to the compilation.

Headers in the above locations can be found by include directives like `#include <header>`. `#include "header"` directives can also find headers in those locations, but they are more relevant for the following case.

When you do `#include "header"`, your compiler will first try to find "header" relative to the directory of `foo.cpp` if it *includes* it, despite `foo.cpp` directory being in search paths or not. If it doesn't find it there, it will try to look up in the include search paths. So this one is more relevant for headers that are more tied to a specific `.cpp` file and you don't want additional include search paths added to the compilation, or if you prefer to use include directives with relative paths.

So if you use `#include <header>`, `header` must be in some of the include search paths, system or `/some/dir` from `-I` flag. If `header` is relative to `foo.cpp`, but not in search paths, compilation will fail.

If you use `#include "header"` and `header` is not in any of the include search paths, it can still be found relative to `foo.cpp` location.

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio, not gcc. And gcc doesn't handle C++ correctly; for that you should use g++.

Comment: @PeteBecker yo C++ expert. I used gcc on `gcc -v -E -x c++ -`, which is correct to get the header's list for C++, and used g++ elsewhere.

Comment: @PeteBecker And the question is not flagged as visual studio, he is using it. What I've described also applies to clang (which, by the way, operates in same way to get header's list, you use clang, not clang++ there). And the idea is the same if he applies it on msvc.

Comment: s/you use clang, not clang++ there/you **can** use clang as well as clang++ there/

Comment: @PeteBecker fyi and to be flat out clear, what defines the headers listing is `-x c++` or `-x c`, regardless of using `gcc` or `g++`. If you take the flag out, you just get the C header list, even if you use `g++`.