# Using relative path for header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using VS code for a project and have a class called "Date" that is defined in "Date.h" header file. I also have a class called "Student" that needs to have a Date as one of its data values. I tried using #include"Date.h" at the top of Student.h, but it says it can't find Date.h. I also tried using a relative path, but it still can't find it. I need this to work on another system other than my own so I can't use the actual path as it will be different on the other system.

Linked here is the [file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qRMd.png) any help is very appreciated.

```
Assignment 1
      |
      |
      |___CourseRegistration
      |
      |___Date
      |     |___Date.cpp
      |     |___Date.h
      |     |___DateTestDriver.cpp
      |       
      |___Student
            |___Student.cpp
            |___Student.h
            |___StudentTestDriver.cpp
```

Comment: What relative path did you try to use, and how did it fail?

Comment: So did you use `#include "../Date/Date.h"`

Comment: What did you use for the relative path? How are your include paths set for the project?

Comment: Generally all of your includes need to be relative to one of your compiler's "include path"s - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41415601/3282436) question for more details.

Comment: So sorry all forgot to include what i'm using. I tried #include "../Date/Date.h" and #include "Date.h". It says "Date.h" no such file exists

Comment: Why would Date.h include Date.h? Date.cpp should work with `#include "../Date/Date.h"` and so should `Student.cpp`

Comment: Are you seeing actual build errors or just red squiggles in the IDE?

Comment: So I did ../Date/Date.h and it still said it could find it, but I tried running it and it found it and works now. Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: `Assignment 1` its not great to have a space in a file or folder name. This can cause you build failures.

Comment: The Intellisense compiler which is in charge of the read squiggles is separate from building and has totally separate settings.

Comment: I generally can't be bothered to put up with sorting this smurf out, so I specify the root as an include folder and not use `""`at all. Set the folders up correctly and `#include <Date/Date.h>` will always work no matter how much you shuffle things around.

Comment: This isn't a common way to structure the files of a single project/library. Often the header files are separated out to their own folder. It seems a little redundant to have each file in a folder of the same name. I think it's more common to have all the headers in one folder and all the sources in another.